# Unable to run git clone from git.videolan.org

Tags: git, vlc

I am trying to clone git repo of vlc media player from **git.videolan.org**, but its failing even though I tried some tips mentioned in similar questions on SO 
Getting following errors while trying to clone with different protocols :

```
gaurav@pruthi-linux:~/projects$ git clone git://git.videolan.org/vlc.git
Cloning into 'vlc'...
fatal: unable to connect to git.videolan.org:
git.videolan.org[0: 88.191.250.118]: errno=Connection timed out
git.videolan.org[1: 2a01:e0d:1:3:58bf:fa76:0:1]: errno=Network is unreachable

gaurav@pruthi-linux:~/projects$ git clone https://git.videolan.org/vlc.git
Cloning into 'vlc'...
fatal: https://git.videolan.org/vlc.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

gaurav@pruthi-linux:~/projects$ git clone ssh://git.videolan.org/vlc.git
Cloning into 'vlc'...
ssh: connect to host git.videolan.org port 22: Network is unreachable
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

But git.videolan.org is accessible

```
gaurav@pruthi-linux:~/projects$ ping git.videolan.org
PING albiero.videolan.org (88.191.250.118) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from albiero.videolan.org (88.191.250.118): icmp_req=1 ttl=45 time=301 ms
64 bytes from albiero.videolan.org (88.191.250.118): icmp_req=2 ttl=45 time=274 ms
64 bytes from albiero.videolan.org (88.191.250.118): icmp_req=3 ttl=45 time=260 ms
64 bytes from albiero.videolan.org (88.191.250.118): icmp_req=4 ttl=45 time=267 ms

--- albiero.videolan.org ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 260.338/275.904/301.349/15.557 ms
```

Comment: possibly a firewall issue? This works fine from my machine.

Comment: @Mureinik any idea how to bypass the same...if its really a firewall issue

Comment: If this is the issue, you should direct that question to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me. Maybe a network problem was produced. Retry again. Check firewall, proxies, etc. Anyway, it was downloaded very slow ant the repo is quite big, be patient.

*EDIT:*

According to official [Videolan wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/Git#Getting_VLC_or_x264_source_code_via_Git), there is an official repo using HTTP as protocol, try using it, maybe the firewall is opened for this protocol and port:

```
git clone http://repo.or.cz/r/vlc.git
```